# How to redirect Urls with variables to the main domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string, query-variables

Using .htaccess, I have tried some things to redirect Urls with variables to main the domain `www.my_domain.tld`, but I didn't find the right way.

I have 2 kinds of Urls that I want to redirect to my main domain:

- `http://www.my_domain.tld/blog/?p=125` *("125" could be any number from 1 to 999)*
- `http://www.my_domain.tld/blog/feed/?p=72` *("72" could be any number from 1 to 999)*

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding your edit following mine Loic, here are some style notes - they are genuinely intended to be helpful. Firstly, [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is an acronym, so should be in all-caps. Secondly, it is a fairly established writing guideline that small numbers, usually less than ten, are written as text and not as numerals ([see this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=numbers+as+text+less+than+ten)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following rule in /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/\?p=([0-9]+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/feed/\?p=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.tld? [L,R,NC]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the destination url is important as it discards the old query strings.